# How to call method by string name in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have a string whose content is name of 1 function in my WP apps. For example, assume that I have:

```
string functionName = "button3_Click"
```

So I would like to call the button3_Click() in my apps. I tried the GetRuntimeMethod method in System.Reflection but the result returned is null, so when I use invoke I got the System.NullReferenceException. My code to call this function is:

```
System.Type[] types = { typeof(MainPage), typeof(RoutedEventArgs) };
string functionName = "button3_Click";
System.Type thisType = this.GetType();            
MethodInfo method = thisType.GetRuntimeMethod(functionName, types);
object[] parameters = {this, null};
method.Invoke(this, parameters);
```

And the prototype of button3_Click is:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

So how can I call the function whose name contained in the string? Thank you so much for you help.

**Update** 
I can call the button3_Click() method by changing access level of this method to public, is there any way to keep access level of this method is private and I can call this method? Thank you for your help.
**Finally**
I think I should use the code like this, it can get all method even its access level is private or public:

```
System.Type[] types = { typeof(MainPage), typeof(RoutedEventArgs) };
string functionName = "button6_Click";
TypeInfo typeinfo = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo();
MethodInfo methodinfo =  typeinfo.GetDeclaredMethod(functionName);
object[] parameters = {this, null};            
methodinfo.Invoke(this, parameters);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try to use [`GetTypeInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.introspectionextensions.gettypeinfo) method on `thisType` and then use [`TypeInfo.GetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo.getmethod) with `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic` flags.

Comment: @Alovchin: I can't see GetMethod in the TypeInfo object. Maybe I have to use the GetRuntimeMethod but I need a way to get private method.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I use the GetDeclaredMethod and it's ok for me now.

Comment: Are you sure GetDeclaredMethod returns you a MethodInfo of a private method?

Comment: @Alovchin: Yes, I tried. I can get both public method and private method :)

Comment: Okay, it's strange since the documentation mentions that it returns **public** declared methods, but if it works for you this means that it's behavior differs in Windows Runtime. I changed my answer below to reflect this correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app is a Windows Runtime app, use [`GetTypeInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.introspectionextensions.gettypeinfo) extension method on `thisType` and then use [`TypeInfo.GetDeclaredMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo.getdeclaredmethod) method:

```
using System.Reflection;
...
System.Type thisType = this.GetType();
TypeInfo thisTypeInfo = thisType.GetTypeInfo();
MethodInfo method = thisTypeInfo.GetDeclaredMethod(functionName);
object[] parameters = {this, null};
method.Invoke(this, parameters);
```

It is said in documentation that `GetDeclaredMethod` returns all *public* members of a type, but according to [.NET Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/reflection/typeinfo.cs.html#1c000ee9fa962fa1), the documentation seems to be incorrect: it calls `Type.GetMethod` with [flags constant](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/type.cs.html#fd17ab140c14ea05) that contains `BindingFlags.NonPublic`.

Comment: I tried GetDeclaredMethod in a portable class library and it only returns public methods.

Answer (score 1):

There are restrictions on Silverlight reflection:

> In Silverlight, you cannot use reflection to access private types and members. If the access level of a type or member would prevent you from accessing it in statically compiled code, you cannot access it dynamically by using reflection. ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc(VS.95).aspx))

Look into `LambdaExpressions` as it might be a workaround in this case.

Comment: It seems the app is written in Windows Runtime though.

Comment: @Alovchin are you sure? `GetMethod()` is unavailable for some reason.

Comment: @MadSorcerer As far as I know in Windows Runtime apps the `System.Type` class is a projection of [`Platform::Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh755828.aspx) class and so it doesn't contain much .NET's System.Type members. In order to have access to more functions, one should call `GetTypeInfo` method I mentioned in my answer and use `System.Reflection.TypeInfo` object.

Comment: @Alovchin: I can't see GetMethod in the TypeInfo object. Maybe I have to use the GetRuntimeMethod but I need a way to get private method.